# Why use do.call here?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is an example of **ggplot2 Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis**

```
geom_mean <- function(..., bar.params = list(), errorbar.params = list()) {
  params <- list(...)
  bar.params <- modifyList(params, bar.params)
  errorbar.params <- modifyList(params, errorbar.params)

  bar <- do.call("stat_summary", modifyList(
    list(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar", fill = "grey70"),
    bar.params)
  )
  errorbar <- do.call("stat_summary", modifyList(
    list(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", geom = "errorbar", width = 0.4),
    errorbar.params)
  )

  list(bar, errorbar)
}
```

It shows

[image]

In this code, what's `do.call()` roll?

I don't know why this code needs `do.call()`.

What is the another function to replace `do.call()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do.call` invokes a function using arguments provided as a list.
For example,

```
 do.call("plot", list(x = 1:10, y = 1:10))
```

will result to

```
plot(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
```

Such approach allows to work with arbitrary argument number, which are 
caught by

```
params <- list(...)
```

Then you can first modify some of them as you wish and later call the function `stat_summary` with this modified list:

```
do.call("stat_summary", params)
```

**The reason is that `stat_summary` itself takes an arbitrary number of arguments (see `...` 
in its documentation).** If you are to describe all possible argument names,
which user might provide, it would result to a lot of unflexible code 
(imagine, that `stat_summary` will get more options in the next version and
have always to update your code accordingly).

Comment: Summarizing your explaining, Because `geom_mean()` takes `...` and `stat_summary()` can take `...` , We have to use do.call(). So the function become more flexible. Right?

Comment: right. It is relevant if you would like to have `...` . But if you define it as `geom_mean(width = 0.4)` then you can simply write
`errorbar <- stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", geom =  "errorbar", width = width)`.  If you wish to provide an access to all aesthetics, you would have to define all of them literally (e.g. `alpha`, `colour`, `width` etc., see ?geom_errorbar). Or use `...`.